# Re ordenar arreglo asociativo en php

Tags: php, array, backend

Hola comunidad recientemente he estado trabajando con un arreglo en php el cual llega desordenado tal cual lo muestro aquí:

```
["Asoc1" => "Dist1", "Asoc2" => "Dist2", "Asoc3" => "Dist1"]
```

Por lo cual lo quiero ordenar de esta manera:

```
["Dist1" => ["Asoc1", " Asoc3"], "Dist2" => ["Asoc2"]]
```

Podrían asesorarme de cómo ordenarlo, saludos!

Comment: La verdad es que no termino de entender exactamente qué quieres obtener, ni qué has intentado. Prueba con las funciones `sort()` y `ksort()`  que puedes encontrar en php.net

Comment: lo que necesito hacer es agrupar los valores de que se repiten a una sola llave y que las llaves pasen a ser los valores del arreglo, no se si me explico

Comment: Que has intentado? Las preguntas que solo buscan respuesta sin mostrar código/investigación previa no son bien recibidas en SOes, revisa [ask]

Comment: He intentado investigado sobre los arreglos asociativos si se pudiese ordenar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es esto:

```
$nuevo_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $data){
    $nuevo_array[$data][] = $key;
}
```

Lo que he hecho simplemente es volver a recorrer tu variable "array" y en la iteración le voy asignando los valores como los necesitas en la variable "nuevo_array".

Comment: Excelente, me ha ayudado te agradezco mucho